# How to animate SF Symbol in a TabView in SwiftUI on iOS 17+

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

With iOS 17 Apple gives us the possibility to animate SF Symbols using the new `symbolEffect()` modifier. I'm not able to animate symbols in a `TabView`. I show you some code:

```swift
struct MyApp: App {
    @State private var gearTabEffect: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        WindowGroup {
                TabView {
                    DashboardView()
                        .tabItem { Label("Dashboard", systemSymbol: ._01Square) }

                    SettingsView()
                        .tabItem { Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear").symbolEffect(.pulse, value: gearTabEffect) }
                        .onAppear {
                            print("settings view appeared")
                            gearTabEffect.toggle()
                        }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or it's a bug (or feature )?

Comment: You have done everything correctly :) The problem is that unfortunately seems like SwiftUI doesn't allow any animations for the tab items. If you put the label outside TabView it will animate correctly

Comment: @narek.sv Hope it'll be fixed soon. I guess that some apps that implemented this effect in the tab bar developed a custom bar so, as there's no way to make it work.